# Toolbar is not working same in different devices Android Studio

Tags: android, toolbar, android-version, android-api-levels

I was working on an app with some pages in it. During my development phase I always tested my code with an Android Virtual Device (API: 22, Android 5.1), after publishing the app I downloaded it to my phone (API: 26, Android 8.0) and faced it with differences which i was not expecting. The source of problems was the toolbar.

`android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` with this code I set both title's and back button's color to white however title's color was grayish and all letters were changed to uppercase.

In my sub-activities I overrode `onOptionsItemSelected` method and

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setActionBar(toolbar);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

used these methods to use back button. However, only one of the back buttons worked, others were useless.

Most probably its because of version difference, but couldn't find the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try Below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

<style name="Theme.Custom.Dark"parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.AppCompat</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Custom.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Custom.Dark</item>
</style>

</resources>
```